# How to get first element ID from XML in jQuery which works perfectly in IE

Tags: jquery, element

I have following XML in **this.treeSpec** variable.

```
<root>
    <item id="9PQ0" pathId="08Z" specId="9PQ0" rel="MainRequest">
        <content>
            <name>ABC</name>
        </content>
    <item id="9PQ02" pathId="08Z2X" specId="9PQ0" rel="property">
        <content>
            <name>ABC1</name>
        </content>
    <item id="9PQ02" pathId="08Z2" specId="" ruleId="CYZ3F7WM861" rel="E" >
        <content>
            <name>ABC2</name>
        </content>
    </item>
```

To get first item ID I am using below code.

```
var rootNode = $(this.treeSpec).find("item").first();
var rootId = rootNode.attr("id");
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Mozilla but it is not working in IE.

Can any one tell me how can we write code to work in IE as well.

Comment: Your first two `<item>` elements are missing their closing tags - is that a typo?

Comment: Yes . Its just a format . There will be closing </item> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the actual solution, but try wrapping your xml in element like div and then try doing find, like:

```
$("<div>" + this.treeSpec + "</div>").find("item")...
```

Hope it helps